# Spatial Join not joining all records with 'JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY', 'KEEP_ALL' option using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I am trying to perform a spatial join that will join all my join features (along with their attributes), within a specified distance, to my target features. Given the nature of the datasets, this should more than double the number of records in the target feature class (taking into account that not all of the join features are within the specified search radius). However, this join appears to rarely be functioning accurately.

My target feature class consists of ~7000 records and when joined accurately via a 'JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY', 'KEEP_ALL'  spatial join contains ~16000 records. However, at least ~90% of the time the spatial join produces just under 8000 records. This join is an integral part of a long script, and incorrect joins propagate into subsequent calculations.

I am able to get the spatial join tool to run correctly using the same layers and options in ArcMap 10.4 or in ArcGIS Pro 1.4. Though, the Python script seems to be producing unreliable results when ran in Visual Studio leveraging arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis.

The script was originally using Python 2 and ArcGIS 10.4. I switched to Python 3 (3.5.2) using a fresh Conda 3 download and the ArcGIS Pro Python package hoping that this may fix it. No luck.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Here is the line of code for the spatial join:

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis (
    "SubLayer_Layer_2", 
    "pp_trans_GUJoin_Layer_2", 
    SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin_UniqueSubs, 
    'JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY', 
    'KEEP_ALL', 
    "#", 
    'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 
    .000002)
```

Here is a code leading up to the spatial join:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import time
start = time.time()
print(start)
print("Start")
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True

defaultGdbPath = r'\\networkpath\data'
 
    ###########################################################

subLayer=defaultGdbPath + '\Subs'
transLayer=defaultGdbPath + '\Tran'
ppLayer=defaultGdbPath + '\PP'

transLayer_Points = defaultGdbPath + '\Tran_Pts'


############################################################################


pp_trans_GUJoin = defaultGdbPath + '\pp_trans_GU_SpatialJoin'
file_name_0 = '\SubLayer_pp_trans_GUSpatialJoin'    
SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin = defaultGdbPath + file_name_0

file_name_1 = '\SubLayer_pp_trans_GUSpatialJoin_UniqueSubs'
SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin_UniqueSubs = defaultGdbPath + file_name_1

#######################
#add new count field for distinct count for PP count 
arcpy.AddField_management(
    subLayer, 
    "SUBID", 
    "SHORT", 
    "", "", "", "", 
    "NULLABLE", 
    "NON_REQUIRED", "")

#calculate field == Join_Count
arcpy.CalculateField_management (
    subLayer, 
    "SUBID", 
    "!OBJECTID!", 
    "PYTHON_9.3")


#########################
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(
    transLayer, 
    transLayer_Points, 
    "BOTH_ENDS")

##############################

#Make feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ppLayer, "ppLayerSpatJoin")

#Make feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(
    transLayer_Points, 
    "transLayerSpatJoin")

#spatial join of feature layers
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis (
    "transLayerSpatJoin", 
    "ppLayerSpatJoin", 
    pp_trans_GUJoin, 
    'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE', 
    'KEEP_ALL', 
    '#', 
    'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 
    .0005) 


#add new count field for distinct count for PP count 
arcpy.AddField_management(
    pp_trans_GUJoin, 
    "Join_Count_PP", 
    "LONG", 
    "", "", "", "", 
    "NULLABLE", 
    "NON_REQUIRED", "")

#calculate field == Join_Count
arcpy.CalculateField_management (
    pp_trans_GUJoin, 
    "Join_Count_PP", 
    "!Join_Count!", 
    "PYTHON_9.3")

#Make feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(subLayer, "SubLayer_Layer")

#Make feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(subLayer, "SubLayer_Layer_2")

#Make feature layer 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(
    pp_trans_GUJoin, 
    "pp_trans_GUJoin_Layer")

#Make feature layer 
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(
    pp_trans_GUJoin, 
    "pp_trans_GUJoin_Layer_2")

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis (
    "SubLayer_Layer_2", 
    "pp_trans_GUJoin_Layer_2", 
    SubLayer_pp_trans_GUJoin_UniqueSubs, 
    'JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY', 
    'KEEP_ALL', 
    "#", 
    'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 
    .000002)
```

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with your code except for being unnecessarily verbose and missing an apostrophe on defaultGdbPath, though I assume that line was changed when adding into your question. It's a bit hard to see what is actually happening, not having any of the data to play with, can you find an incorrect situation and screen shot it then explain what it should be.

Comment: The "keep all" option in both ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro does not seem to work after the latest update. I have tested joins and relates in both programs now (2/21/23) and both only return matching records.